# How can I show the color of a value in a <td> tag in C# based on condition?

Tags: c#, html-table

I have a service build that sends mail. I create a table and send the values as an e-mail. I want to do it as <td style style='background-color:green> when my string values, for example, "Torque" value is "low". But I didn't know how to use the If condition here. My code is as below.

```
string aa = "<html> <style> table, th, td { border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse; }</style><body> " +
                 $@"
            <table style='width: 100 %'>
           <tr>
              <th>Engine</th>
             <th>Risk(Torque)</th>
             <th>Risk(Flow)</th>
             <th>Risk(Power)</th>
           </tr>";
        foreach (var item in valuesRodBreak)
        {
            aa = aa + $@"
                  <tr>
                   <td>{item.Engine}</td>
                   <td>{item.Torque}</td>
                   <td>{item.Flow}</td>
                   <td>{item.Power}</td>
                  </tr>
                ";

        }
        aa += $@"</table></body></html>";
```

I want to do it as <td style style='background-color:green>{item.Torque} in the  tag above, which can be according to the if condition or something else. How can I do this?

Comment: Actually, I want to make <td style='background-color:red> if the value inside the <td> tag, that is, {item.Engine}, is "Low", <td style='background-color:green> is "High" @TimSchmelter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use methods:

```
private string GetColorStyleAttribute(string value)
{
    switch(value)
    {
        case "Torque": 
            return " style='background-color:green";
        // ...
        default: 
            return "";
    }
}
```

---

```
aa = aa + $@"
      <tr>
       <td{GetColorStyleAttribute(item.Engine)}>{item.Engine}</td>
       <td{GetColorStyleAttribute(item.Torque)}>{item.Torque}</td>
       <td{GetColorStyleAttribute(item.Flow)}>{item.Flow}</td>
       <td{GetColorStyleAttribute(item.Power)}>{item.Power}</td>
      </tr>
    ";
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that's exactly what I wanted, but I couldn't get it right in my head. Thank you very much indeed